# search for a variable in a text file

Tags: python

im trying to search for a variable in a text file.

```
sid = '185'
a = ((sid)"\n")
with open(filename) as f:
  data = f.readlines()


if a in data:
        print 'its here'
else:
        print 'its NOT here'
```

here is my foo.txt

> ['306\n', '303\n', '313\n', '323\n', '417\n', '281\n', '304\n', '322\n', '320\n', '319\n', '308\n', '310\n', '414\n', '415\n', '314\n', '312\n', '307\n', '305\n', '285\n', '286\n', '318\n', '283\n', '282\n', '294\n', '309\n', '416\n', '418\n', '321\n', '185\n']

i think my problem lies with defining the /n properly? Not sure, as you can tell im a beginner. Any help or recommendations on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  can you tell us what it does when you run it ?

Comment: this gave me what i was looking for.

Comment: thank you , now i just need to vote this accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) and following list comprehension to grub the numbers,then use `in` operand for check the membership:

```
>>> s = """['306\n', '303\n', '313\n', '323\n', '417\n', '281\n', '304\n', '322\n', '320\n', '319\n', '308\n', '310\n', '414\n', '415\n', '314\n', '312\n', '307\n', '305\n', '285\n', '286\n', '318\n', '283\n', '282\n', '294\n', '309\n', '416\n', '418\n', '321\n', '185\n']"""
>>> import re
>>> def check(var):
...    return var in [int(i.strip()) for i in re.split(r'[\[\]\',]*',s) if i.strip()]
... 
>>> check(303)
True
>>> check(444)
False
```

And in your case you need to use `open(filename).read()` instead of `s`.Also for larger files you can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#module-sets) that is more efficient for checking membership:

```
>>> def check(var):
...    return var in set(int(i.strip()) for i in re.split(r'[\[\]\',]*',s) if i.strip())
... 
>>> check(444)
False
>>> check(305)
True
```

Comment: i see how this will work also but it might be to much for what i need. regardless thank you .

Comment: @wwi you're welcome! so if you have found this answer helpful you can tell this to community by voting and accepting the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.search` function to search for a string

```
foo = """['306\n', '303\n', '313\n', '323\n', '417\n', '281\n', '304\n', '322\n', '320\n', '319\n', '308\n', '310\n', '414\n', '415\n', '314\n', '312\n', '307\n', '305\n', '285\n', '286\n', '318\n', '283\n', '282\n', '294\n', '309\n', '416\n', '418\n', '321\n', '185\n']"""

sid = '185'
a = sid + '\n'

if re.search(a,foo):
     print "its here"
else:
     print "its not here"
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, if there could be more than one line in `foo.txt` you can use:

```
sid = '185'
a = sid + '\\n'
filename = 'foo.txt'
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if a in line:
            print 'its here'
            break
    else:
        print 'its NOT here'
```

Don't forget to escape the backslash with `'\\n'` if `foo.txt` really is literally as you give it.